# How to Load image in uiwebview?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am doing following steps to display a html file in uiwebview.

1.unzip the .epub file, from that get html file content in a array

> NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
>
> ```
> [arrayDatacontent addObject:data];
> ```

after this process complete. Removed the unzip .epub file.

  2.

> > NSData *htmlString=(NSData *)[arrayDatacontent objectAtIndex:2];
>
> NSString *imagePath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
>
> ```
> imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
>
> imagePath = [imagePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
>
> [webview4epub loadData:htmlString MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:/%@//",imagePath]]];
> ```

from this content text loaded in the webview. But there relative images is not shown.

Comment: Why do you expect a method designated for loading a string to load arbitrary binary data?

Comment: @H2CO3: sorry, i edit above, but same issue occur..

Comment: Of course, because you made the very same mistake. Raw image data is **still** not HTML.

Comment: In the html img scr location image is available. I deleted only the html file images are there. Even though it will not link that particular image path.